# Windows 10 Answer File: How to automate Edition Selection

Tags: windows-10, automation, answerfile

I work for an MSP where my job is mainly to take the computers that we receive from Dell and reimage them. I have automated part of the setup with an answer file. Specifically the part after windows installs and it gets to the OOBE.

However, I am trying to automate it from the start of the Setup, namely where it asks which version I wish to install and lists every version of Windows 10 under the sun. Currently, my answer file looks like this:

```
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <TimeZone>Eastern Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Name>Administrator</Name>
                        <DisplayName>Administrator</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Administrators;Power Users</Group>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <OOBE>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
                <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
                <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
            </OOBE>
            <AutoLogon>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <Username>Administrator</Username>
                <LogonCount>1</LogonCount>
            </AutoLogon>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallFrom>
                        <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                            <Key>/IMAGE/NAME</Key>
                            <Value>Windows 10 Enterprise</Value>
                        </MetaData>
                    </InstallFrom>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/users/ME/desktop/test/sources/install.wim#Windows 10 Enterprise" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

Ive tried to do it like this, which I saw on this forum somewhere:

```
                    <InstallFrom>
                        <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                            <Key>/IMAGE/NAME</Key>
                            <Value>Windows 10 Enterprise</Value>
                        </MetaData>
                    </InstallFrom>
   </OSImage>
```

And tried the /IMAGE/INDEX with a value of 3, as well as straight entering the Product ID for Windows 10 Enterprise and nothing seems to work so far.

Ive searched quite a bit, and I cannot find a way.

The code listed above is in a file called "unattend.xml". If I name it autounattend, it breaks everything and will not run at all.

The file is located in D:\sources$OEM$$$\Panther which is where the answer file was installed when I made the boot drive with RUFUS

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be a separate file? See here about Catalog File https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/update-windows-settings-and-scripts-create-your-own-answer-file-sxs?view=windows-11#step-1-create-a-catalog-file

Comment: @YisroelTech Ive made the catalog file before. It didnt work up until now. I might have done something wrong. Ill retry the catalog file in case i screwed something up. If it works ill update my original post to mention that

Comment: @YisroelTech Ive gotten it past the version selection by using the ei.cfg file, which i had ignored up until this point, because I read that it would just be ignored if there was an answer file on the drive.